# Change header background every 24 hours

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to change my header background image every 24 hours?

All my images are stored in a folder called header-images.

Comment: Wake up. Have a cup of coffee and then copy the file. Repeat 365 times per year

Comment: We need more details: change in what manner? To all users, or just one user? In random? In its current form it's really hard to come with actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

if it's an image you want every hour, why not having 24 images in that folder and name it with the hour?

in your master template script use:

```javascript
var dt = new Date(),
    currentDay = dt.getDate(); // [0-31]
$("body").css("backgroundImage", "/images/bkg_" + currentDay + ".jpg");
```

and then you should have each day image as

```
/images/bkg_0.jpg
/images/bkg_1.jpg
...
/images/bkg_30.jpg
/images/bkg_31.jpg
```

If you want if random, you need to have access to the folder (so you know how many and witch files are available), and you can't from javascript (for security reasons) you need to use a dynamic language such as ASP.NET or PHP...

Comment: Change to all users. Random order is fine.

Comment: if the script is in your master template, it will apply to everyone... do you understand what is a master-template page/script? Same way you append Google Analytics scripts... needs to be on every page.

Comment: I am trying to change the header background every day, not every hour, but thanks for the example.

Comment: do you understand what is a master-template page/script? Yes i do:)

Comment: sorry, my bad, read "every 24 hours" as "every hour" :D - answer updated.

Comment: ASP.NET or PHP is not a option

Comment: then you need to have one image for each hour and load as I specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = ["path/to/image1.png", "path/to/image"];
setInterval(function () {
     var path = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length];
     $("#header").css("background", "url(path)");
}, 1000 * 60 * 24);
```

But this will change it only for one user, not for all.

For changing to all users you need server side code or a function that will change it using values that are changed for all users (for example date/time).

Comment: I am looking for a solution without entering every image path, there  might be 200 images. It will be suicide to do that.